# Unable to inspect variables on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm unable to inspect variables on eclipse when debugging remote Java application. What could be the reason.

EDITED:
I'm  not able to inspect any variables. Message shown in inspector mini window is '*variable name* cannot be resolved'. I'm able to see the contents when I run it locally with test code.

Comment: Tell us more. What happens when you try inspecting the variable?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse v 3.10

Comment: Well, I think what you mean is 3.1.0. I'd recomend switching to current release. It might fix this issue. I personally am using version 3.4, and remote debugging works like a charm :)

Comment: Thank you Marcin. Will try that out.

Answer (score 8):

Be absolutely certain that the classes deployed to the remote server have been compiled with debug information.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you're connected to the remote app.

If your application has multiple threads, it might be that no thread is selected, in this case - select the thread that debugger stop in.

If debugger hasn't stopped - set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I was compiling the project through Maven with debug=false for the compiler-plugin. This was the problem!

Answer (score 1):

All variables or just some? There could be several reasons for this:

- There is no debugging info available for that class. You wouldn't see the variables either when debugging the same code locally.
- Maybe there is a bug in Eclipse. Did you check the error console?
- I'm not sure whether the version of the VM makes any difference. But you should try to use the same VM on both sides to make sure.

Comment: If Java app exposes remote debugging capabilities it is not necessary for a class to implement *Serializable* interface.

Comment: Hey Aaron, remote debugging will work with all classes Serializable or not.

Comment: Fixed. Wasn't there an option to tell Java to forget the debug data in the class files? I check the docs but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two views by which you can see values while debugging in Eclipse.  First is the Expressions view.  In the Expressions view you can see values for fields that you indicate you want to 'watch.'  Second is the 'Values' view.  In the Values view, you can see the values for fields in a method  that you are stepping through, if the class was compiled with debug tokens, or the values of the arguments passed in if the class was not compiled with debug on.

If you are seeing something like '*Variable name cannot be resolved*' it could be that you are using the Expressions view, not the Values view.

Comment: 'Values' or the 'Variables'?

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same problem and checked that all classes were compiled with debug info and they were.

I found the problem to be that the local source was slightly out of date. The source of the code I was debugging had not changed between the two versions but the problem was still occurring.
Once I updated from Subversion and rebuilt locally the problem was resolved.

Comment: I've modified the source while debugging and saved it. From next time, I didn't get to inspect the values. Reverting the changes solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

There could be many possible reasons behind.
Are you in 'proper context'? If your debugger is at one context or stack frame and you are trying to inspect variables that are not in that scope then you won't be able to inspect them.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem after switching to building with maven.  To get round the problem I added the  tag to the compilerArguments tag in the pom.xml.  Find the maven compiler-plugin tag and modify it so it looks something like below, the new tag you are interested in adding is the empty  tag!!:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <g></g>
                </compilerArguments> 
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```